# The product of any two even integers is a multiple of 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The product of any two even integers is a multiple of 4."

This is what I have so far:

let n, m be even integers and let D be a integer that is divisible by 4.

n=2k.

m=2l.

d=4p.

such that k,l,p exists in Z (integers).

n • m = d

2k • 2l = 2(k.l)

2(k•l)=4p.

is that correct??

if that is correct what to do next??

Comment: $2k\cdot 2l=2(k\cdot l)$? Seems weird, if $l=k=1$, then $2k\cdot 2l=4$.

Comment: You are assuming in the beginning that $d$ is divisible by 4. You should not do that, and instead show that it is using only $m$ and $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a rectangular grid of small squares with length $l$ and width $m$, then $l\cdot m$ is equal to the number of squares in the whole grid.

If $l$ and $m$ are even numbers, you can divide the whole grid into blocks of squares, measuring $2\times 2$. Each of those blocks contain $4$ squares, so the total number of squares divided by $4$ is the number of blocks, which is an integer. Therefore $l\cdot m$ can be divided by four, or in other words, $l\cdot m$ is a multiple of four.